# FCKEditor Integration in Swing

Tags: java, swing, fckeditor

I have successfully integrated the FCKEditor in swing application.
Now I am trying to achieve that:

1>When the user click in the editing area, an event is to be fired, taking its id.(might use javascript but donot know how to configure in swing).

2>Then that id is to be shown in a jlabel. So, i want to communicate the native editor with swing application.

I tried a lot but without any major success.
special vote of thanks for any help.

Comment: FCKEditor  is JPanel or JComponent?

Comment: i tried this one:  http://djproject.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/djproject/DJNativeSwing-SWTDemo/src/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/demo/examples/htmleditor/FCKEditorExample.java?pathrev=R-1_0_1

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your editor is `JPanel`.
You can try to add [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) to your FCKEditor for the next way:

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

private JLabel yourLabel;

public Example() {
    yourLabel = new JLabel("test");

    JPanel component = new JPanel();
    component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseReleased(e);
            String id = getIDMethod();
            //if your editor contains id you can use next code
            //String id = ((JPanel)e.getSource()).getIDMethod();
            yourLabel.setText(id);
        }
    });

    getContentPane().add(component,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    getContentPane().add(yourLabel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String...strings ){
    Example e = new Example();
}

protected String getIDMethod() {
    return "1";
}

}
```

Here `component` - it's your editor. You add MouseListener for that. Next in method `mouseReleased` you get ID and set it to the label(here `yourLabel` your target label).

Try this code, I think it's help you

Comment: i refered from here:  http://djproject.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/djproject/DJNativeSwing-SWTDemo/src/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/demo/examples/htmleditor/FCKEditorExample.java?pathrev=R-1_0_1

Comment: If you use FCKEditorExample(as you mentioned) to which component you tried to add `MouseListener`?

Comment: i applied it to JHTMLEditor reference.

Comment: In your example add `MouseListener` to `htmlEditor` object in FCKEditorExample, and it must hook events. Please, Show code how you have tried to do that.

Comment: JHTMLEditor htmlEditor = new JHTMLEditor(HTMLEditorImplementation.FCKEditor,        JHTMLEditor.FCKEditorOptions.setCustomJavascriptConfiguration(configurationScript));
jPanel1.add(htmlEditor);
htmlEditor.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
     {
         System.out.println("got it here");
     }
});

Comment: Try to use mousereleased instead of mouseclicked